# Distance vector algorithm - maximum paths with 4 points

Tags: algorithm, graph, bellman-ford

while programing bellman-ford algorithm I encountered one problem, it's question more theoretical than technical but here it is:

I have 4 points A,B,C,D, cost from A to B equals 3 etc. here is the graph:

```
B--3--C
|     |
3     9
|     |
A--1--D
```

Let's say I want to know what cost is from A to C via D, will it be: `10` ? or it will go from A to D (which cost is 1) then back from D to A (total cost is 1+1=2) then from A to B (1+1+3=5) and from B to C (1+1+3+3=8) so it will be `8` not `10` ?

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find any rational answer to my question.

**EDIT:** 
let's say that for A->D and D->C paths count will be 2 and for A->D then D->A then A->B then B->C there will be total paths count equals 4 so will it choose the way with shortest paths count (paths count = 2) or the longer one (paths count = 4)?

Comment: i think the algorithm forbids visiting a node more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the *via* problem, I wouldn't use single go of the algorithm; I would call it twice. First, for `A -> D`, then for `D -> C`, as that is practically the problem; then, final path is sum of those two.

*Note: I'm not familiar with Bellman-Ford algorithm; this answer is just a general remark regarding pathfinding.*

Comment: your answer fits very well I think, since as far as I understood it, the Bellman-Ford algorithm itself has no concept of "via"

Comment: @Griwes yeah but let's say that for `A->D` and `D->C` paths count will be 2 and for `A->D` then `D->A` then `A->B` then `B->C` there will be total paths count equals 4 so will it choose the way with shortest paths count (paths count = 2) or the longer one (paths count = 4)?

Comment: @takeit, **you are summing costs of edges, not counting them**. Shortest path  for `A -> D` = 1. Shortest path for `D -> C` = 7. Therefore, shortest path from A to C via D is (shortest `A -> D`) + (shortest `D -> C`) = 1 + 7 = 8.

Comment: @Griwes yes I know it, but I read that this can be done only in 3 steps, firstly you point out costs costs to the `neightbours` then  `neightbours` -> `neightbours` and `neightbours` -> `neightbours` -> `neightbours` so its like 3 steps, and here we can do it in 2 steps or in 4 steps so we choose the shortest way, or am I wrong here ?

Comment: @takeit, the algorithm forbits visiting a node more than once, as EyalAr noted under your question. Therefore, **there is no concept of *via* in the algorithm**. To find such thing, you must - however you would want to do it - run the algorithm twice: once finding a way to "*via*" node, then to the final destination. Otherwise, you would rarely find the shortest way, thanks to situations similar to the one in question: oddly distributed edge costs - and your question was "how to find shortest way", wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no negative-weight cycles, then every shortest path visits each vertex at most once.